# Minimum Wildfly version that supports Servlet 3.0

Tags: java, wildfly, wicket

I'm trying to migrate a project from Wicket 1.4.17 to 7.10.0. The page for Wicket 7.x says that "Servlet" 3.0 is required. The page for Wicket 8.x says that Wildfly 10 supports the minimum Servlet version (3.1 in that case). But the Wicket 7.x page just says Servlet 3.0 is needed but does not say which versions of various app servers have it.

I can't find anything online, either randomly or at the Wicket and Wildfly websites that says which version of Wildfly has Servlet 3.0. What is the minimum version of Wildfly that supports Servlet 3.0? We currently have clients on 8.2.1. Is this good enough?

I ask because I'm having some really weird stack traces in the log that never reference our code, so I'm trying to rule out version mismatches (the tops of the traces always mention the Undertow parts of Wildfly). In my searching, others have had these errors, but never get an answer.

Comment: All versions of WildFly are Java EE 7 which. Java EE 7 supports servlet 3.1 and the servlet spec should be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1):

both Wicket 7.x and 8.x are tested with Wildfly 8.2.1, so your version should match perfectly (See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/wicket-7.x/testing/wicket-arquillian/pom.xml).
This mail discussion might help you:

http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Deploy-wicket-examples-8-x-at-Wildfly-10-td4676800.html

Comment: Ok, because the thing is I keep getting java.nio.BufferOverflowExceptions referencing .js and .css files (some are mine, some are wicket's), with the top few lines being: "        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:363) [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:859) [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]
        at io.undertow.util.HttpString.appendTo(HttpString.java:204) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]"

Comment: We are also using Wicket 7 with the whole spectrum from WFLY 8.2.0 to 12.0.0

Comment: I'm not very familiar with WildFly, but it might be a  problem of buffer sizing:

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/240185

Answer (score 1):

On the JBOSS Wiki page https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS they say that Servelet API 3.0 is there since JBOSS AS 6, so all wildfly versions have at least Servlet API 3.0.

From what i see Widlfy 8.2.0 to 12.0.0 have servlet API 3.1 - the file is called `jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar`. On WildFly 12 there is a bit newer file: `jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar`

We are using Wicket 7 with the whole spectrum from WFLY 8.2.0 to 12.0.0